# Get unique value as per sorting key up to certain count (SQL)

Tags: sql

I would like to get 5 unique value as per sorted key. 
Below is the table example:-
[image]

Expected result is 5,10,3,9,1. First unique 5 value from table. 
Thanks.

Comment: Please tag the DBMS

Comment: SELECT TOP(5) Value, Count(Value) From TableX Group by value OR SELECT TOP(5) Distinct Value FROM TableX. Here 5 can be parametrized too

Comment: SELECT TOP(5) Value, Count(Value) From TableX Group by value order by serial

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For SQL Server**

```
select TOP 5 value   from table1
group by value
order by min(Serial)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following for `Oracle`:

```
select * from (
    select value
    from table
    group by value
    order by min(serial) 
) where rownum <=5
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this(**For MySQL**):

```
SELECT DISTINCT value FROM <table-name> ORDER BY serial LIMIT 5;
```